# How to force wrap table row cells

Tags: html, css

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name:</th>
    <td>Apple</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Color:</th>
    <td>Golden</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How do I style the `tr` so that my output will look something like this (below). I want to force it... meaning that no matter the width available, it should wrap

```
Name:
Apple
Color
Golden
```

**I know it is possible to do it with `divs`... But a solution for table is what Im looking for**

*Why would i want to do something like this?..  Because Im trying to make my table responsive.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flex`.

```css
tr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name:</th>
    <td>Apple</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Color:</th>
    <td>Golden</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ``align-items: flex-start`` is not needed: default value

Comment: Also if you put this in a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) you can make it so that it's only for small screens (to make it responsive)

Comment: @Khaki `stretch` actually.

Comment: Those not a fan of `flex` could use  ` tr > th, tr > td { display: block }`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a direction for your table rows:

```
tr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Hope it helps!